# Can't import numpy into embedded ironpython engine

Tags: python, ironpython, numpy, ironclad

From an ipy console I can

```
import ironclad
import numpy
```

with no problem.

However when I try the same imports with an embedded interpreter the numpy import fails.  My Python engines is set up like this:

```
    public PyEngine()
    {
        //Frames option needed to use sys.__getframe
        //used in Numpy and others.
        Dictionary<string, object> opts = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        opts["Frames"] = ScriptingRuntimeHelpers.True;

        engine = Python.CreateEngine(opts);
        scope = engine.CreateScope();
        runtime = engine.Runtime;
    }
```

And I execute statements like this:

```
    public void ExecuteStatement(string statement)
    {
        if (statement.Length > 0)
        {
            WriteInputToOutput(statement);

            try
            {
                ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(statement, SourceCodeKind.Statements);
                object result = source.Execute(scope);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteExceptionToOutput(ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

The exception prints out this message:

```
    Error executing code:
System.ArgumentException: Specified path is invalid.
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.ThrowInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run2[T0,T1,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonFunction.FunctionCaller`1.Call1(CallSite site, CodeContext context, Object func, T0 arg0)
   at load_module$836(Closure , PythonFunction , Object , Object )
   at IronPython.Compiler.PythonCallTargets.OriginalCallTarget2(PythonFunction function, Object arg0, Object arg1)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonFunction.FunctionCaller`2.Call2(CallSite site, CodeContext context, Object func, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , CodeContext , Object , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.Call(CodeContext context, Object func, Object arg0)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.FindAndLoadModuleFromImporter(CodeContext context, Object importer, String fullName, List path, Object& ret)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.TryLoadMetaPathModule(CodeContext context, String fullName, List path, Object& ret)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.TryGetExistingOrMetaPathModule(CodeContext context, String fullName, List path, Object& ret)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportModule(CodeContext context, Object globals, String modName, Boolean bottom, Int32 level)
   at IronPython.Modules.Builtin.__import__(CodeContext context, String name, Object globals, Object locals, Object fromlist, Int32 level)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , CodeContext , Object , String , PythonDictionary , PythonDictionary , PythonTuple )
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.Import(CodeContext context, String fullName, PythonTuple from, Int32 level)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Operations.PythonOps.ImportTop(CodeContext context, String fullName, Int32 level)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Utils.InvokeHelper`4.Invoke(Object arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Utils.ReflectedCaller.Invoke(Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.CallInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run1[T0,TRet](T0 arg0)
   at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.InvokeTarget(Scope scope)
   at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.Run(Scope scope)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.InitializeModule(String fileName, ModuleContext moduleContext, ScriptCode scriptCode, ModuleOptions options)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.CompileModule(String fileName, String moduleName, SourceUnit sourceCode, ModuleOptions options, ScriptCode& scriptCode)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.CompileModule(String fileName, String moduleName, SourceUnit sourceCode, ModuleOptions options)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadFromSourceUnit(CodeContext context, SourceUnit sourceCode, String name, String path)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadModuleFromSource(CodeContext context, String name, String path)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadPackageFromSource(CodeContext context, String name, String path)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadFromDisk(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, String str)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPathHook(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, List path, Func`5 defaultLoader)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPath(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, List path)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportNestedModule(CodeContext context, PythonModule module, String name, List path)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportModuleFrom(CodeContext context, Object from, String name)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportModule(CodeContext context, Object globals, String modName, Boolean bottom, Int32 level)
   at IronPython.Modules.Builtin.__import__(CodeContext context, String name, Object globals, Object locals, Object fromlist, Int32 level)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , CodeContext , Object , String , PythonDictionary , PythonDictionary , PythonTuple )
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.Import(CodeContext context, String fullName, PythonTuple from, Int32 level)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Operations.PythonOps.ImportBottom(CodeContext context, String fullName, Int32 level)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Utils.InvokeHelper`4.Invoke(Object arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Utils.ReflectedCaller.Invoke(Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.CallInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run1[T0,TRet](T0 arg0)
   at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.InvokeTarget(Scope scope)
   at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.Run(Scope scope)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.InitializeModule(String fileName, ModuleContext moduleContext, ScriptCode scriptCode, ModuleOptions options)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.CompileModule(String fileName, String moduleName, SourceUnit sourceCode, ModuleOptions options, ScriptCode& scriptCode)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.CompileModule(String fileName, String moduleName, SourceUnit sourceCode, ModuleOptions options)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadFromSourceUnit(CodeContext context, SourceUnit sourceCode, String name, String path)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadModuleFromSource(CodeContext context, String name, String path)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadFromDisk(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, String str)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPathHook(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, List path, Func`5 defaultLoader)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPath(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, List path)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportModule(CodeContext context, Object globals, String modName, Boolean bottom, Int32 level)
   at IronPython.Modules.Builtin.__import__(CodeContext context, String name, Object globals, Object locals, Object fromlist, Int32 level)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , CodeContext , Object , String , PythonDictionary , PythonDictionary , PythonTuple )
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.Import(CodeContext context, String fullName, PythonTuple from, Int32 level)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Operations.PythonOps.ImportStar(CodeContext context, String fullName, Int32 level)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Utils.ActionHelper`3.Invoke(Object arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Utils.ReflectedCaller.Invoke(Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.CallInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run1[T0,TRet](T0 arg0)
   at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.InvokeTarget(Scope scope)
   at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.Run(Scope scope)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.InitializeModule(String fileName, ModuleContext moduleContext, ScriptCode scriptCode, ModuleOptions options)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.CompileModule(String fileName, String moduleName, SourceUnit sourceCode, ModuleOptions options, ScriptCode& scriptCode)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.CompileModule(String fileName, String moduleName, SourceUnit sourceCode, ModuleOptions options)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadFromSourceUnit(CodeContext context, SourceUnit sourceCode, String name, String path)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadModuleFromSource(CodeContext context, String name, String path)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadPackageFromSource(CodeContext context, String name, String path)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadFromDisk(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, String str)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPathHook(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, List path, Func`5 defaultLoader)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPath(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, List path)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportModule(CodeContext context, Object globals, String modName, Boolean bottom, Int32 level)
   at IronPython.Modules.Builtin.__import__(CodeContext context, String name, Object globals, Object locals, Object fromlist, Int32 level)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , CodeContext , Object , String , PythonDictionary , PythonDictionary , PythonTuple )
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.Import(CodeContext context, String fullName, PythonTuple from, Int32 level)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Operations.PythonOps.ImportWithNames(CodeContext context, String fullName, String[] names, Int32 level)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Utils.InvokeHelper`5.Invoke(Object arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2, Object arg3)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Utils.ReflectedCaller.Invoke(Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.CallInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run1[T0,TRet](T0 arg0)
   at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.InvokeTarget(Scope scope)
   at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.Run(Scope scope)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.InitializeModule(String fileName, ModuleContext moduleContext, ScriptCode scriptCode, ModuleOptions options)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.CompileModule(String fileName, String moduleName, SourceUnit sourceCode, ModuleOptions options, ScriptCode& scriptCode)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.CompileModule(String fileName, String moduleName, SourceUnit sourceCode, ModuleOptions options)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadFromSourceUnit(CodeContext context, SourceUnit sourceCode, String name, String path)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadModuleFromSource(CodeContext context, String name, String path)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadFromDisk(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, String str)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPathHook(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, List path, Func`5 defaultLoader)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPath(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, List path)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportModule(CodeContext context, Object globals, String modName, Boolean bottom, Int32 level)
   at IronPython.Modules.Builtin.__import__(CodeContext context, String name, Object globals, Object locals, Object fromlist, Int32 level)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , CodeContext , Object , String , PythonDictionary , PythonDictionary , PythonTuple )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute6[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Types.BuiltinFunction.BuiltinFunctionCaller`5.Call4(CallSite site, CodeContext context, TFuncType func, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.Import(CodeContext context, String fullName, PythonTuple from, Int32 level)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Operations.PythonOps.ImportTop(CodeContext context, String fullName, Int32 level)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Utils.InvokeHelper`4.Invoke(Object arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Utils.ReflectedCaller.Invoke(Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.CallInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run1[T0,TRet](T0 arg0)
   at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.InvokeTarget(Scope scope)
   at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.Run(Scope scope)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.InitializeModule(String fileName, ModuleContext moduleContext, ScriptCode scriptCode, ModuleOptions options)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.CompileModule(String fileName, String moduleName, SourceUnit sourceCode, ModuleOptions options, ScriptCode& scriptCode)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.CompileModule(String fileName, String moduleName, SourceUnit sourceCode, ModuleOptions options)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadFromSourceUnit(CodeContext context, SourceUnit sourceCode, String name, String path)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadModuleFromSource(CodeContext context, String name, String path)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadPackageFromSource(CodeContext context, String name, String path)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadFromDisk(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, String str)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPathHook(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, List path, Func`5 defaultLoader)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPath(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, List path)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportTopAbsolute(CodeContext context, String name)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportModule(CodeContext context, Object globals, String modName, Boolean bottom, Int32 level)
   at IronPython.Modules.Builtin.__import__(CodeContext context, String name, Object globals, Object locals, Object fromlist, Int32 level)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Utils.InvokeHelper`7.Invoke(Object arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2, Object arg3, Object arg4, Object arg5)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Utils.ReflectedCaller.Invoke(Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Actions.Calls.MethodCandidate.Caller.Call(Object[] args, Boolean& shouldOptimize)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Types.BuiltinFunction.BuiltinFunctionCaller`5.Call4(CallSite site, CodeContext context, TFuncType func, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.Import(CodeContext context, String fullName, PythonTuple from, Int32 level)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Operations.PythonOps.ImportTop(CodeContext context, String fullName, Int32 level)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Utils.InvokeHelper`4.Invoke(Object arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Utils.ReflectedCaller.Invoke(Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.CallInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run2[T0,T1,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.RunWorker(CodeContext ctx)
   at IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.Run(Scope scope)
   at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.InvokeTarget(Scope scope)
   at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.Run(Scope scope)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.SourceUnit.Execute(Scope scope, ErrorSink errorSink)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptSource.Execute(ScriptScope scope)
   at STKinterpreter.PyEngine.ExecuteStatement(String statement) in D:\Documents and Settings\demarep\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\STKinterpreter\STKinterpreter\PyEngine.cs:line 97
```

As far as I can tell my sys.path has correct directories.  What else should I be looking into?

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of things that you can try:

1. Make sure the you have setup the IRONPYTHONPATH system variable
   properly to find the *numpy* module. Most of the time that's installed
   within your CPython directory structure, so you need to add the
   paths listed below.
2. As an alternative you can try to set the `sys.path` within your code, dynamically.

Assuming that you have CPython 2.6 series installed, these are the paths you should look into:

- C:\Python26\Dlls
- C:\Python26\Lib
- C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the above, but only worked when I moved the project to a "valid" path. That is one without space characters. I wonder if it is because of the UNICODE poor support of ironclad.