# How can I use –X:Frames in C# 2.0 to load ironpython?

Tags: c#, ironpython, dynamic-language-runtime

I can use ironpython 2.6 (not for .net 4) load numpy, running ipy with -X:Frames or -X:FullFrames on the command line.

But, if I want to use Ironpython/DLR in C# 2.0 to load the py file, how can I use  -X:Frames or -X:FullFrames?

I tried it like this:

```
        var lang = Python.CreateLanguageSetup(null);
        lang.Options["Frames"] = ScriptingRuntimeHelpers.True;
        var setup = new ScriptRuntimeSetup();
        setup.LanguageSetups.Add(lang);
        var runtime = new ScriptRuntime(setup); 
        var engine = runtime.GetEngine("py");

        engine.ExecuteFile("test.py");
```

But, it didn't work!
So, is there anyone can give me a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think frames working or not working is your problem.  If I take your code and put:

```
import sys
sys._getframe()
```

into test.py it works if I have the 'lang.Options["Frames"] = ScriptingRuntimeHelpers.True;' line and fails if I don't.  That indicates the option is working fine.

So what is the error you're getting?  It might be that you need to set something which the command line normally does - such as sys.path which maybe needs the current directory and/or ".".  Or maybe site.py needs to be imported.  Or maybe IronClad  is installed in the DLLs directory and auto-loaded so you need to do runtime.LoadAssembly(...) on it's DLL.

Comment: I tred sys._getframe() and it's OK, and running ipy console with -X:Frames is also ok. Only load py by ironpython in C# 2.0. I uploaded my code (Visual studio 2010 solution, but .net 2.0 project):http://1oz7ga.blu.livefilestore.com/y1pbhO4fRA4M7KUlnk0Oi19-dTmSUhRdj2rQ6tguLebK829d9WykIUoc3vQEvuhlkhFU6xIT_cCOXjGB9TOMo064a-Qzcb4gbea/ex_vs10_cs%20load%20ipy%20ironclad.rar?download&psid=1

Comment: You should change "*.rar_" to "*.rar" of the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Your question looks similar to this one:
[Can't import numpy into embedded ironpython engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358731/cant-import-numpy-into-embedded-ironpython-engine)

But, maybe you should give more info about what errors you got...

Comment: Have you tried to check your paths, as suggested in the link ?

Comment: I run "test.py" with "ipy.exe -X:Frames". It's OK, no problems. So I think it is Frames setup problem.